# How to remove light bounce / reflection from objects?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting, reflection

[image]

Hi there. I'm creating a scene with many images tacked up onto the wall. I use 'Images as Plane' to import these images and add a solidify modifier to give it some thickness. It is rendered on cycles.

It seems that there's some light bounce from the back of the paper. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe disable the *Diffuse* option in the *Obect panel > Visibility > Ray Visibility*?

[image]